# Unwanted .html extension after mod_rewrite rule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^readnews/([0-9]+)\.html$ readnews.php?news_art_id=$1
```

This works but messes up my images.

The images folder is in a directory before the url `http://localhost/newsdev/images` but after re-write I get `http://localhost/newsdev/readnews/123.html`.

Please how can I also rewrite to remove the `.html`?

I would like to have `http://localhost/newsdev/readnews/123`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression you've posted should not be matching pictures. It's possible that you've misread the symptoms.

My educated guess is that you are liking images with a relative path. Since you are relocating the HTML document, you need to fix the paths accordingly.

- `images/foo.jpg` from `/newsdev/readnews.php` is `/newsdev/images/foo.jpg` [X]
- `images/foo.jpg` from `/readnews/314.html` is `/readnews/images/foo.jpg` [OK]

Or you can simply use absolute paths:

- `/newsdev/images/foo.jpg` is always `/newsdev/images/foo.jpg`

As about removing the .html suffix, it doesn't exist until you put it there yourself. Just don't add it:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^readnews/([0-9]+)$ readnews.php?news_art_id=$1
```

Comment: Thank you. Please how can I rewrite http://localhost/newsdev/news.php ---- to http://localhost/newsdev/news

Answer (score 1):

This will not rewrite if the request is a file or a directory on the disk

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

To remove the html at the end you could use

```
RewriteRule ^readnews/([0-9]+)$ readnews.php?news_art_id=$1
```